# Left margin between icons and NavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, navigationview

I have to add a left margin between the icons and the `NavigationView`, in arrow in the image bellow:

[image]

I know that according to google specs, this margin must have `16dp` but I need to change it. I have tried:

```
 <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">64dp</dimen>
 <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">20dp</dimen>
```

But still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397268/android-navigationview-reduce-space-between-icon-and-text-and-itembackground

Comment: You can try using these steps to override it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913570/how-to-overcome-this-item-padding-in-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xml layout of that item is [`design_navigation_item.xml`](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_navigation_item.xml)

```
<android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="true"/>
```

As you can see, paddings that are applied are taken from the activity's theme - `listPreferredItemPaddingLeft` and `listPreferredItemPaddingRight`. Thus, you have to apply your custom theme to `NavigationView` overriding those attributes with necessary values.

In `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyNavigationViewItemStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

We want to change **only** those two attributes from activity's theme, thus we are extending the theme, that is applied to the activity.

In layout `xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:theme="@style/MyNavigationViewItemStyle"/>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For my case I added one line to xml: app:itemHorizontalPadding="@dimen/horizontal_padding_on_nav_drawer"

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space48"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_nav_header"
    app:insetForeground="@color/black"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/background_selected_menu"
    **app:itemHorizontalPadding="@dimen/horizontal_padding_on_nav_drawer"**
    app:menu="@menu/drawer">
```

Comment: Works on material NavigationView.