# How do I change the horizontal spacing of icons in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I would like to know how do I change the size of the indicated space in the navigation drawer

[image]

I tried  creating a style and then using android:layout_marginLeft but it would also affect the nav_header, I just want the margin on the icons from the left.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code. What have you implemented?

Comment: @BakaWaii I don't have any code for what I'm asking, all I have is some stuff on dimens.xml

    <dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">33dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_margin" tools:override="true">60dp</dimen>

Comment: Are you using `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`?

Comment: @BakaWaii Yes I am

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left margin between icons and NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919406/left-margin-between-icons-and-navigationview)

Comment: Notes: You may not see the immediate effect on the preview.