# NavigationView Items Padding in Android

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview, material-components, material-components-android

How do I set padding for items inside NavigationView.I need to set paddingLeft for items as I have removed icons.What i have tried is this but it is not working:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/selected_background"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer" />
```

My Drawer.xml file in styles:

```
<style name="Drawer">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try this hope its gonna work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914592/7104450

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome this item padding in navigation drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913570/how-to-overcome-this-item-padding-in-navigation-drawer)

Comment: @SumitShukla you want padding between icon and textview inside the naviagtionView..?

Comment: @SardarKhan. No I have removed all those icons and I want all textView to be padded from Left...

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone wants to adjust the padding for the items in the NavigationDrawer using the latest material design, checkout these new attributes *app:itemIconPadding* and *app:itemHorizontalPadding*.

**app:itemIconPadding** will adjust the padding between your icon and the item's text
**app:itemHorizontalPadding**, as its name suggest, will adjust the padding from the left and right horizontally for the item.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            app:itemIconPadding="16dp"
            app:itemHorizontalPadding="10dp"

            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />`
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using a menu without icons you can use the **`app:itemHorizontalPadding`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemHorizontalPadding="2dp"
    ../>
```

The result with default value and custom value:

[image]
[image]

Use the `app:itemShapeInsetStart="0dp"` to change the margin of the shape:

[image]

Comment: hi, this is unrelated but how can I achieve that active indicator that has margins and rounded corners

Comment: @GilbertMendoza Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933739/add-custom-shape-ripple-with-selector-on-navigationview-menu-item/58683034#58683034

Answer (score 4):

you can change "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" value for changing navigation item vertical padding in your application theme

```
<!-- Your application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- THIS LINE-->
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">54dp</item>
</style>
```

(default value is 48dp)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this value ion dimension file under the res->values->dimension folder and add the following line of code.

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_padding" tools:override="true">8dp</dimen>
```

Comment: I have removed all the icons.so am i able to use it.

Comment: try adding icon and then try it.

Comment: But i am supposed to do it without icons.

Comment: why you don't want to show icons.? it can elaborate your text and make it easy for user.

Comment: I am asked to so.That's why!!

Comment: You can refer to this post as well.

Comment: <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">1dp</dimen> try this.

Comment: you can also check this post if any thing not working  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397268/android-navigationview-reduce-space-between-icon-and-text-and-itembackground/36417267#36417267

Comment: Not worked!! Thanks for your effort. Is there a problem with my code or anything I am missing....

Comment: you can try it with icons including ..and if works then tell me i will tell you a work around for it..

Comment: You can make your own custome naviagtion drawer you can control all thing..but it takes time.